# How to create credit card PAN generator based on a specific pattern?

Tags: c#, algorithm, credit-card, banking

I'm building a system for a small bank for card issuance, what I need is how to make the system generate Card Number sequence (or PAN) based on a specific pattern.
For example, First six digits of PAN are the bank BIN: 517070
The next two digits are product code: let's say 30 (Could be any number)
the next two digits are branch code: let's say 01
the rest of the digits will be generated randomly (of course the last digit is a check digit)

My questions: is there an algorithm to help me implement these requirements in the system?

This website matches my requirements 
https://www.elfqrin.com/discard_credit_card_generator.php

Thank you

Comment: Is PAN just the credit card number? If so, there are many credit card number generators on sites like GitHub, etc. - did any of them match your requirements?

Comment: Seems like, you need some king of luhn algorithm for that, have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249670/implementing-luhn-algorithm-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @John yes it is just a credit card number.
I will look it up, but so far I didn't find anything that matches my requirements. thank you

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, yes the generated number should be validated using luhn algorithm. 
Thank you I will have a look

Answer (score -1):

Use String Format :

```
          Random rand = new Random();
          string bin = "517070";
          string productCode = "30";
          string branchCode = "01";
          int randNumber = rand.Next(0, int.MaxValue);
          string number = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", bin, productCode, branchCode, randNumber.ToString("D20"));
```

Comment: You need to be *certain* that the random number part is not a duplicate.  A simple `rand.next()` is insufficient.  Three common ways to ensure uniqueness are 1) keep a list and check for duplicates. 2) shuffle and take the next shuffled number 3) encryption.  There a lot of questions discussing the problem on this site.

Comment: I know.  This question is not about a random number.  It is about generating a 30 format string that consists of four parts.

Comment: @jdweng the number should be a valid credit card number (PAN), and this can be achieved using luhn algorithm and shouldn't be any random number.

Comment: I know.  I just showed how to format a 30 character string made of 4 parts.  You did not specify how to generate the PAN so I just put in a random number to get a 30 character string.  You said "the rest of the digits will be generated randomly"