# Validating Israeli ID number

Tags: luhn

I'm looking for a clean and efficient way to validate an Israeli ID number.

It's basically an implementation of the [Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) on a 9 digits number.

**Note:**
This question is here for the community because it wasn't on stack overflow yet.
You can add answers in different coding languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an efficient way to implement it in C# ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57890411/3545572)):

```
public static bool IsValidIsraeliID(string israeliID)
    {
        if (israeliID.Length != 9)
            return false;

        long sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < israeliID.Length; i++)
        {
            var digit = israeliID[israeliID.Length - 1 - i] - '0';
            sum += (i % 2 != 0) ? GetDouble(digit) : digit;
        }

        return sum % 10 == 0;

        int GetDouble(long i)
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0: return 0;
                case 1: return 2;
                case 2: return 4;
                case 3: return 6;
                case 4: return 8;
                case 5: return 1;
                case 6: return 3;
                case 7: return 5;
                case 8: return 7;
                case 9: return 9;
                default: return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

JS example code like it appears in Wikipedia:
[https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/ספרת_ביקורת](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%AA)

```
function IDValidator(id)
{
    if (id.length !== 9 || isNaN(id)) {  // Make sure ID is formatted properly
        return false;
    }
    let sum = 0, incNum;
    for (let i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
        incNum = Number(id[i]) * ((i % 2) + 1);  // Multiply number by 1 or 2
        sum += (incNum > 9) ? incNum - 9 : incNum;  // Sum the digits up and add to total
    }
    return (sum % 10 === 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = list(input("הזן מספר תעודת זהות כולל ספרת ביקורת\n"))
num_1 = num[:-1]
num_2 = int(num[-1])
num_3 = num_1[::2]
num_4 = num_1[1::2]
num_5 = []
number = 0
for i in num_4:
    i = int(i)*2
    if i > 9:
        a = i//10
        b = i%10
        i = a+b
    num_5.append(i)
for i in num_3:
    i = int(i)
    num_5.append(i)
for i in num_5:
    number += i
number = number%10
if number + num_2 == 10:
    print ("מספר תקין")
else:
    print ("מספר לא תקין")
```